# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'net-snmp-config --libs' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, flask, net-snmp, easysnmp

```
PS D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS> & d:/AMS2.0/AMS/AMS/myenv/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(myenv) PS D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS> & d:/AMS2.0/AMS/AMS/myenv/Scripts/python.exe d:/AMS2.0/AMS/AMS/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS\app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from easysnmp import Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'easysnmp'
(myenv) PS D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS> pip install easysnmp
Collecting easysnmp
  Using cached easysnmp-0.2.6.tar.gz (43 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      'net-snmp-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS\myenv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-_vsuuyqw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel       
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-_vsuuyqw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-_vsuuyqw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-build-env-_vsuuyqw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 44, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'net-snmp-config --libs' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
(myenv) PS D:\AMS2.0\AMS\AMS>
```

I want to use easysnmp in my python flask code but due to this kind of error unable to get the success. i have already installed net-snmp using exe still facing the same issue.

Comment: Isn't the error clear? It can't find the command `net-snmp-config`. You probably haven't set your PATH correctly to include the folder that contains it.

Comment: Yes, but the executable not available in net-snmp folder,
i have already installed net-snmp and m able to use snmpwalk to get details.
but in my case when going to install easysnmp then throwing error that net-snmp-config executable not found how to resolve this error. i have already added environment path "C:\usr\bin"